# How do I handle backAndroidHandler in each scene using react-native-router-flux

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-router-flux

As the title description, I'm using react-native-router-flux.

And there is a question, I used `backAndroidHandler={true}` in `<Router/>` work normally before.

But now, because some reason I have to set `backAndroidHandler` to control physical back button enable in different scene.

So I can't just put it in router something like this before:

Example:

```js
<Router
    backAndroidHandler={true}>
    <Scene key="a" />
    <Scene key="b" />
    <Scene key="c" />
</Router>
```

How could I setting `backAndroidHandler` in different scene or in the Tag to achieve this without `setState` (Because it will rerender again at route page)?

I have tried someone said in other question using like `<Scene key="c" type={ActionConst.RESET}/>` didn't work.

Any help or recommend will be appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching some times, I found another way to achieve this effect.

Use `BackHandler` from `react-native` to add a listener to listen physical back button trigger, and then compare with `react-native-router-flux` `Actions.currentScene` to defined what should they do in different page like this:

```js
import { Text, StyleSheet, Image, View, BackHandler, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
...

class ResultsView extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick); //here
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
  }
  handleBackButtonClick() {
    let cs = Actions.currentScene;
    if (cs === "APage" || cs === "BPage" || cs === "CPage" || cs === "DPage") {
      console.log("nono square don't pop!")
    } else {
      Actions.pop()
      console.log("touch to pop here")
    }
  }
...
```

And then set the `backAndroidHandler` in router to true:

```js
<CustomRouter backAndroidHandler={true}>
...
```

And it works fine.